# Automatic download via ftp

Tags: windows, ftp, windows-7, backup, windows-server-2012

I want to set my machine to automatically download a file via FTP access, at some interval every day. I have windows 7 and windows server 2012.
Does anyone have any idea how to enable this?

Comment: FTP.EXE is somewhat scriptable, create a batch file, add it as a scheduled task

Comment: You can use also winscp and a scheduled tigger.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911751/copy-files-from-sftp-with-cmd/40912376#40912376

For schedueling with Winscp.

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule