# Copy files from SFTP with CMD

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, sftp, connect

We have a customer with their SFTP site, and I would like to copy files from specific folder, by using any automated process.

One of the example which I found, is **winscp.net**, but I have not managed how to use it, for my purpose.
http://www.itworld.com/article/2928599/windows/how-to-automate-sftp-file-transfers-in-microsoft-windows.html

**QUESTION:** All I will need is not run script and the file should be copied from their directory to my local folder. Is it possible at all?

I found the way of using PSFTP(Putty) to connect to the server, but how to make it automatically, do not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its a good solution for your problem.

You have to install winscp and the code some files and it will do automaticaly. I used 3 or 4 times. Also you need the key for your SFTP to connect throught it.

Here a link to the guide step by step.

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guides

Here is a link to the scripting webpage

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting

I recommend you to create an ini file to load all of the characteristics of your ftp connection and then execute an script over this.

It can be launched like that

```
WinSCP.com /ini=[your ini file] /script=[Your script file(what you want to do when it is connect)]
```

Hope this helps!.